# Shortest path from Shieldbreaker to Engineer

Tags: optimization, class, wfrp-2e

Playing as a Shieldbreaker, I found a distinct lack of Dwarf-only advancements that would lead to other Dwarfy classes but for Runebearer, which would lead to the Runesmith classes. There ain't no [Ironbreakers](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Ironbreakers) or [Longbeards](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Longbeards), no [Hammerers](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Hammerers) or [Irondrakes](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Irondrakes) exist as individual classes... The only Dwarf-Only Path is back to Runebearer and into Runesmiths, or going all Un-Dwarf Pit Fighter and then taking the Slayer's path. But that ain't no paths that one wanna take!

No, my Shieldbreaker shall thread the shortest path to Engineer, so he can someday plow under the pesky Greenskins and Beastmen, and everything that has fallen to the ruinous powers with the power of the only human invention worth anything: a [steam tank](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Steam_Tank). But this begs the question:

What is the shortest path that is available without taking a non-career exit? The shortest in this context is taking the least number of advances and class changes needed while with equal length between two paths, the best path is the one that adds the most non-duplicate Skills and Talents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Playing around with the [career list](http://bindslet.dk/rpg/whfrpcareers.html), gives that the shortest path to Engineer is via Deepwatcher, from the WFRP Companion. This career has Shieldbreaker as entry and Engineer as exit.

None of the other Engineer entries (Artisan, Miner, Student, and Tradesman) are exits from Shieldbreaker, making this the shortest path by default. It also requires no additional advancements.

Comment: great, that is the only class that they literally forgot to add that on both Engineer and Shieldbreaker in the Career Compendium entries and only have it on the Deepwatcher...

Comment: ...and the dip into Deewatcher is completed by just *taking* it: Shieldbreaker has either the same or more advancements required on all stats to complete it.